# Who was able to resist more punches from Saitama, Boros or Garou?

Tags: one-punch-man

It's known few characteres can resist punches from Saitama when he's half serious (probably only Boros, Garou and Orochi until now)

Who was able to resist more punches from Saitama, Boros or Garou?

Comment: Garou never took a serious punch of saitama. I mean there wasn't any intention of killing in it. But when he was fighting against boros there was so those are 2 different punches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### (Warning: webcomic spoilers ahead; shortcomings of spoiler tag formatting makes it overly burdensome to use them)

I'll give a page-by-page rundown of the attacks that we see both Boros and Garou take from Saitama without dying; this won't count the time Garou got smacked for the dine-and-dash incident (or the couple extra times he got hit in the manga version of events before they've actually fought).  The manga/anime version of the Boros fight is a bit different than in the webcomic, but since a proper fight with Garou has to date only occurred in the webcomic we'll have to use the webcomic for both fights to put them on an even footing; or at least "more even".  I think there are more blows thrown by Saitama in the webcomic version, interestingly enough.

### Boros vs. Saitama

- chapter 38 page 06-07    —armor-breaking chest punch
- chapter 38 page 15       —off-screen jump in fight, Boros has lost an arm; possibly many blows have been thrown, at least by Boros, as Saitama is quite a bit dustier than he seemed to be before
- chapter 39 page 13       —running exchange of blows; some are obviously countering each other, others not so much
- chapter 40 page 05       —chest punch
- chapter 40 page 06       —normal punch combo reduces much of Boros to vapor (he regenerates)

The fight then ends with Saitama's next attack, a serious punch, with Boros dying.

It's hard to know exactly how many punches Saitama threw that weren't part of his "consecutive punches"/"combo", due to that jump in the fight (the intervening pages involve the other heroes).  But there's at least 3 normal punches landing a direct hit, a normal punch combo, and 4 or more matched/countered attacks occurring during their running exchange.  We are not given any clear indication that Boros ever dodged any of Saitama's blows, but he does appear to at least counter some or survive having his attacks countered (until the serious punch).

### Garou vs. Saitama

- chapter 88 page 08   — punch to face
- chapter 88 page 13   — shoulder throw into the ground
- chapter 89 page 07   — dodged punch to face
- chapter 89 page 10   — dodged punch to chest
- chapter 89 page 11   — dodged kick to chest
- chapter 89 page 12   — dodged two punches
- chapter 90 page 08   — survives a normal punch combo
- chapter 90 pages 12-13   — two-handed normal punch combo; gets overwhelmed but no real damage (might have deflected them all before escaping)
- chapter 91 page 05   — avoids getting arm grabbed
- chapter 91 pages 06-07   — escapes getting slammed into ground
- chapter 91 page 11   — survives direct punch
- chapter 91 page 13   — survives direct punch to face
- chapter 92 page 09   — gut punch in first monster form
- chapter 92 pages 11-12   — Loses arm to serious headbutt, regenerates it
- chapter 92 pages 14-15   — punched again, transformations start to undo

At this point Saitama says Garou's getting weaker and running on fumes, and he's basically just scolding him.  So the following hits can probably be discarded, but I'll list them for completeness.

- chapter 92 page 17   — slapped around, punched in face;
- chapter 92 page 20   — punched again because he won't shut up
- chapter 93 page 09   — downward hammer punch to head out of annoyance again

That's a normal punch combo, a two-handed normal punch combo, a serious headbutt, and 14 or so other punches or kicks, plus a few other moves, before Saitama declares that he's started getting weaker and just starts slapping him around and scolding him.

Garou dodges or counters many of the attacks, with dodges indicated above.  For direct hits: 5 punches and a slam connected, a normal punch combo connected seemingly in full (at least 14+ impact points from what I can count, but many of them overlap almost completely with others making it hard to be sure), and a two-handed normal punch combo overwhelmed him (he was doing a flurry of his own) but it's not clear if anything actually connected.

### Analysis

Ultimately there's going to be some opinions here as there are some mitigating concerns that aren't addressed in the canon.  Of principle importance to me is: was Boros capable of dodging any of Saitama's attacks?  We don't see him do so, but Boros was also clearly relying on his regeneration, so it's conceivable it was possible for him to do so but he simply elected not to because he could just regenerate the damage.

My personal opinion: Garou wins this comparison.  Here's my list of reasons why.

- Unlike with Boros, we do definitively see Garou reading Saitama's movements, dodging and countering many of them.
- Garou suffers several direct blows without taking lethal damage.
- Garou doesn't lose any body parts to the direct hits until a serious headbutt.
- Garou survives a serious series attack, whereas Boros dies to the only one Saitama uses.  (Saitama also uses a serious table flip during the Garou fight, though this was not really intended to do damage so much as to show off and make Garou fight more seriously.)
- Garou survives two combination attacks, whereas Boros only deals with one.
- The total number of attacks we see directed at Garou is higher, though to be fair to Boros there's an undisclosed number of them that happen off-screen; could be zero, could be a whole bunch, but the rest of the fight suggests it's probably towards the low end.

As for word of god statements, ONE has said a melee Boros vs. Garou would be a hell of a fight.  Many people take this as saying that Boros and Garou are of similar power levels.  However their fighting styles and capabilities are vastly different.  Garou uses skill and technique to control fights and strike at weak points and openings, whereas Boros relies on overwhelming power and regeneration.  Boros also has ranged attacks.  At range Boros would probably win, while head-to-head it'd be an epic clash with no word-of-god victor known.  None of that actually addresses how well either of them deals with blows *from Saitama*, though.  Just makes it easy for each individual fan to pick a side (or go Switzerland and stay out of it or declare them equal).

Comment: But you listed as punches the ones he dodged . So how many actual punches he got from Garou?

Comment: @Pablo Personally I'd consider not getting hit by one of his punches in an actual battle the same thing.  Better, even. I mean do you discount it if he can actually deflect the attack?  Otherwise, 5 punches and a slam connected, a normal punch combo connected seemingly in full (at least 14+ impact points from what I can count, but many of them overlap almost completely with others making it hard to be sure), and a two-handed normal punch combo overwhelmed him (he was doing a flurry of his own) but it's not clear if anything actually connected. Before Saitama said he was getting weaker.

Comment: Compare how a normal combo converted Boros into slightly more than a bloody mist.  Sure he got better, but clearly Garou was withstanding it better than that.  I believe ONE has indicated that he thinks it'd be a hell of a battle between Boros and Garou at his peak (thus far); so in some sense they're at about the same power level, but they don't fight in the same fashions.  Garou basically has the superior skill and melee combat ability, while Boros is pure power, regen, and ranged attacks. Both come to the conclusion that they were little more than a plaything to Saitama, of course.

Comment: @Pablo oh, and I forgot the serious headbutt in the attacks that hit and he survived. It would not be an unreasonable read to interpret Saitama's statements to mean that he became weaker when he transformed into a monster (Saitama also says he's running on fumes, so whether the monster form was intrinsically weaker or his stamina just gave out is also up for grabs), but it's not clear exactly when he thinks Garou got weaker; might be just as the transformations get undone, or at the monster transformation, or earlier. But serious headbutt is still serious.

Comment: @Pablo I've updated the answer to include a rundown of the Boros fight.

Answer (score 5):

Up until now saitama really did not have to do anything at all to beat garou all it took was one really simple shot(not even a punch)
And in manga too there isn't any fight scene between garou and saitama, it's yet to be revealed if garou would be able to endure punches from him or not
And if you  read the manga you would  be aware of the condition of Orochi.
So far boros is the only one who gave a little fight to Saitama

Answer (score 0):

Well, Saitama did not really fight Garou yet. From the perspective of the anime, Saitama didn't fight Garou yet. Not in an actual fight. Yes they have passed each other paths, even then Saitama just brushed him off. They didn't actually fight. So the answer to your question would be, as for now, Boros is the only one who was able to resist Saitama's punches.

Answer (score 0):

Would probably be Boros. Considering Saitama had to use his "serious mode" in order to defeat Boros. While Garou in the other hand, Saitama just sees him as a random passerby and the two of them have not gotten into an actual fight yet. At the moment, Boros is probably the only one who is able to resist punches from Saitama.